# What changes are needed in this code to give a proper look when i hover on the Product menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

When I hover on the product menu in navigation bar the list items of Product menu is not proper positioned. It shows big block. Please help me.

What changes are needed in this code to give a proper look when i hover on the Product menu?

CSS Code:

```
 #nav_barhorizontal{
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul{
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: #333;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul li{
float: left;
text-align: center;
width: 120px;
margin: 0px;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul li a{
color:  white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px;
display:block;
font-family : Calibri;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active)  {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
margin-left:0px;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul ul
{
    display:none;
}

 #nav_barhorizontal ul li:hover ul
{
   text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
     text-align: left;
}
```

BODY Part Coding:

```
<div id="nav_barhorizontal">
         <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
              <li>
            <a href="">Products</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Temp1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Temp2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Temp3</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li> 
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by setting the `background-color` on the top-level `ul`. The submenu is a descendent of the parent `ul`, so when it is shown, the height of the parent `ul` is increased and the background color extends down to the bottom.

Moving the rule

```
background-color: #333;
```

from the selector

```
#nav_barhorizontal ul
```

to the selector

```
#nav_barhorizontal ul li
```

seems to fix the problem. Here's the new css:

```
#nav_barhorizontal{
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul{
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul li{
float: left;
text-align: center;
width: 120px;
margin: 0px;
background-color: #333;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul li a{
color:  white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px;
display:block;
font-family : Calibri;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active)  {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
margin-left:0px;
}

#nav_barhorizontal ul ul
{
    display:none;
}

 #nav_barhorizontal ul li:hover ul
{
   text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
     text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: @HeliPareshkumarShah You're welcome. Could you please click the little check mark if I've answered your question?